# Best way to replace a self-repeating CSS color vlaue?

Tags: sass, user-defined-functions

In my style.css, I have a color value that repeats itself about 30 times. Going row after row and changing it is Sisyphean. Is there any way to "give a command" to change it to another color fast? Maybe via my text editor (Notepad++), SASS, or some external program?

What would be more efficient you think?

Comment: I started to learn program-coding only a month or so after I first published this question; In the time before, I only did humble amounts of HTML, or, amateur CSS – That is, not in the level of a web designer or anything of the sort, and not in a company with other people that I could ask about such action in a swift way; It was maybe the first time I very much felt the need for something like thiss;

Comment: If I am not wrong, I did try Google but I didn't have a good clue on what I actually need to phrase there as in Hebrew it might have been phrased enough-different then what I actually needed and the results weren't very fertile based on this and/or other reason I eventually decided to ask here.

Comment: Anyway, I believe People should think well before running to click the thumbs down button - They might be missing some very surprising facts and act from bad aggressiveness - That is, for no good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all occurrences of the colorcode should be changed, then you can use the "Find and Replace" function of Notepad++

Press `Ctrl + H` to bring up the Dialog. Insert your old colorcode and your new one and then click `Replace all`

And for easier change later you can define Variables in sass.
Example:

```
$myAwesomeColor: #F9E055;

.text { color: $myAwesomeColor; }
```